# Controlling the outset scale?

Tags: inkscape

When I apply `outset` or `inset` from the path menu in inkscape the result is a very large outset.  Is there a way to set the value that the outset function should use when creating the outset?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's in program preferences. See category "Behaviour". In subcategory "Steps" there's a variable for Inset/Outset step.

Comment: In French: "Comportements" -> "Incréments", third box "Éroder/Dilater de :".